# What does 불 나방 mean?

Tags: spoken-korean, slang

I was watching a variety show and A called B a `불 나방` and this description was used when they were teasing B about being a chicken or scaredy cat because he didn't want to participate in a bet.

Literally, I understand that this means `fire moth` but I know that's not what it meant in this context.

Is this just another term for chicken or scaredy cat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

불나방 (a garden tiger moth) is mainly used to a person who falls
into temptation and pays a high price. That is, a stupid person. It
is negative

(1) Still many people dashed to speculative investment in real estate as
like a garden tiger moth.

아직도 많은 사람들이 부동산 투기에 불나방처럼 달려든다.

(2) His thoughtlessness is like moth's dashing to a fire.

그의 무모성은 마치 불나방이 무작정 불로 달려 드는 것과 같다.

(3) He say moth to us who dashed to cell phone market which is already
controlled

이미 장악된 핸드폰 시장에 띄어든 우리에게 불나방 같다고
했다.

@ Scientific fact : Moth obeys some angle with respect to sun light.
But at night, since it obeys for the light of lantern or candle, so
 obeying brings moth's dash into the fire and thus, it died.